# Цветной текст в квадратных скобках не расскрашивается при изменении ячейки

Tags: excel

Цель - что бы слово в квадратных скобках расскаршиваль в красный цвет. Что не так в коде? Сама функция не отрабатывает на изменения в странице или ошибка в коде? Никаких ошибок нет, в тоже время ничего не раскрашивается, после того как набираю слово в скобках

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Text As String
    Dim Index1 As Long
    Dim Index2 As Long
    Text = Target.Text
    Index2 = 1
    Do
        Index1 = InStr(Index2, Text, "[")
        If Index1 = 0 Then Exit Do
        Index2 = InStr(Index1, Text, "]")
        If Index2 = 0 Then Exit Do
        Target.Characters(Index1, Index2 - Index1 + 1).Font.Color = &HFF
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA в книгу добавляю так - на Страницу1 -  Insert Module и туда вставляю код.

Comment: Нормальный код, должен работать при ручном вводе строки с квадратными скобками (вручную, по одной ячейке за раз!). При обработке целого диапазона (например, вставка значений в несколько ячеек) - выдаст ошибку, свойство `.Text` есть у ячейки, но не у диапазона. И раскрашиваться будут только текстовые строки, а не результат функции. То есть `="Дальше красный [здесь красный] и опять черный"` покрашен не будет

Comment: Код в модуле нужного листа? Работа макросов разрешена? Совет (к вопросу не относится): добавить диапазон срабатывания макроса (не на всем же листе надо красить символы)

Comment: Про excel в целом - макросы разрешены, проверил на примере другого макроса. Про сам код, проверял так - ввожу в ячейку А1 [Hello] и после перехожу на др ячейку. ничего не происходит. Я так понял, этот код - это не совсем то что мне нужно. А нужно мне: [Hello] word в одной ячейки и только внутри скобок вместе со скобками слово было красным.

Comment: >> *ввожу в ячейку А1 [Hello] и после перехожу на др ячейку. ничего не происходит* - код отрабатывает нормально, проверено. При переходе на другую ячейку срабатывает событие и если в измененной ячейке есть текст, обрамленный прямыми скобками, он будет окрашен

Comment: почему у меня не работает? Office Excel 2019 Код вешаю на Страницу1 (в новой книге это единств страница). Страница1 - Insert - Module (вставляю код) И перехожу сразу на страницу где пишу тескт в ячейках.